# Creating CSV file with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to create a CSV file with three headers, and I have two `for` loops which work perfectly when printing on the console, however when I run my code, it only shows data for the first header on Excel and not the other two. Is there any way I can display data for all three headers without running into any problems?

Here is my code:

```py
filename = "kd.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")

headers = ("username, kills, games\n")
f.write(headers)

for i in range(0,len(user)):
    username = user[i].text
    print("username: " + username)

    f.write(username + "\n")
    

for i in range(0,(len(user))*2,2):
    kills = kc[i].text.strip().replace(',', '')
    games = kc[i+1].text.strip().replace(',', '')
    print("kills: " + kills)
    print("games: " + games)

    f.write(kills + "," + games + "\n")
```

Comment: try changing the `'w'` to `'a'`

Comment: `f = open(filename, "a")`

Comment: Ok, now I do have the data for both kills and games, but they are below the data of username, I want the data to go under each specific header.

Comment: Could you provide the source, url, code you are  scraping, maybe you do not need to loop twice. Thanks

Comment: `f.write(["", + "," + kills + "," + games + "\n")`

Comment: The syntax for the above code is wrong, but I managed to move the data for kills and games to the right by on column, now I need to move it up by 100 rows or len(user) in this case.

Comment: I may be mistaken, but what does this question have to do with `beautifulsoup`?  I mean, why is it tagged [beautifulsoup]?

Comment: ahh ya, I see I have a typo in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use pandas for this task.

```
import pandas as pd

filename = "kd.csv"
x = {"username":[], "kills":[], "games":[]}

for i in range(0,len(user)):
    x['username'].append(user[i])

for i in range(0,(len(user))*2,2):
    x['kills'].append(kc[i].text.strip().replace(',', ''))
    x['games'].append(kc[i+1].text.strip().replace(',', ''))

df = pd.DataFrame(x)
df.to_csv(filename)
```